# Javascript - "style.display = element"

Tags: javascript, html

Помогите пожалуйста с кодом "style.display = element".

Этот код работает:

```html
<div id="div-14" style="display:none;">[text text-287 placeholder "Name, Vorname / Surname, Firstname "][text text-345 placeholder "Telefon / Phone number"][text text-346 placeholder "E-Mail"]</div>


<div style="display: inline-block;">
<select onchange="showdiv(this.value);">
                <option disabled selected value></option>
                <option value="0">Yes</option>
                <option value="1">No</option>

      </select></div>
</td>
</tr>


<script type="text/javascript">
function showdiv(element){
document.getElementById("div-14").style.display = element==0?"inline-block":"none";
} 
</script>
```

Как только создаю копию кода выше с другим div (в этом же файле), то работает только один из низ:

```html
<div id="div-15" style="display:none;">[text text-287 placeholder "Name, Vorname / Surname, Firstname "][text text-345 placeholder "Telefon / Phone number"][text text-346 placeholder "E-Mail"]</div>


<div style="display: inline-block;">
<select onchange="showdiv(this.value);">
                <option disabled selected value></option>
                <option value="0">Yes</option>
                <option value="1">No</option>

      </select></div>
</td>
</tr>


<script type="text/javascript">
function showdiv(element){
document.getElementById("div-15").style.display = element==0?"inline-block":"none";
} 
</script>
```

Видимо проблема где то в "style.display = element==0?"

Помогите исправить пожалуйста.

ПОЛНЫЙ КОД:

```html
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Geschäftsführung / Management</td>


      <td><div id="div-14" style="display:none;">ПРИМЕР 1 НЕ РАБОТАЕТ</div></td>


    <td>

<div style="display: inline-block;">
<select name="number" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" onchange="showdiv(this.value);" required>
                <option disabled selected value></option>
                <option value="0">Yes</option>
                <option value="1">No</option>

      </select></div>
</td>
</tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showdiv(element){
document.getElementById("div-14").style.display = element==0?"inline-block":"none";
} 
</script>

<tr>
    <td>Zentrale / Headquarter</td>


      <td><div id="div-15" style="display:none;">ПРИМЕР 2 РАБОТАЕТ И ТАМ И ТАМ</div></td>


    <td>

<div style="display: inline-block;">
<select onchange="showdiv(this.value);">
                <option disabled selected value></option>
                <option value="0">Yes</option>
                <option value="1">No</option>

      </select></div>
</td>
</tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showdiv(element){
document.getElementById("div-15").style.display = element==0?"inline-block":"none";
} 
</script>



</table>
```

Comment: правильно. потому что элемент с конкретным идентификатором должен быть только один на странице...поэтому надо например присваивать другой айдишник другому блоку

Comment: Я присвоил первому скрипту div-14, а второму div-15... но как только оба находятся в одном коде, один из них все равно не работает.. не пойму почему..((

Comment: какому "скрипту"?......... покажи полностью весь код.....весь html и весь js

Comment: Добавил в вопросе.. "Пример 2" высвечивается в обоих случаях. "Пример 1" не работает вообще...

Comment: Всё правильно. теперь у тебя на странице две функции одинаково названные...... с ними правило такое же, как и с идентификаторами..... не может быть тысяча функций с одинаковыми именами

Comment: Аааа.... так "showdiv" это название просто... А не какое-то выполнение кода. Понял. Я просто не программист вообще. Поменял на showdiv2 и все заработало. Спасибо!